# is there an alternative to javascript for accessing the DOM API?

Tags: javascript

Every programming language has many alternatives, however, I could not find any alternative to javascript for accessing the DOM API? Why is this the case?

Thanks.

Comment: What about VBScript in IE?

Comment: @jcubic [VBScript is no longer supported in IE11 edge mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn384057(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have alternatives like Dart, LiveScript, Typescript, Babel and Coffeescript, yet these will be compiled/translated to native Javascript. The reason there is no real alternative is the fact that it is the only standard that is being implemented by all major browser "companies".

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. Javascript is not like other programming languages. An alternative to Javascript must be supported by major web browsers for it to be used at all. This is not the case for general purpose programming languages. So, this makes it very difficult to create an alternative

Comment: Yes, any alternative would require a plugin to work. For example there is Actionscript, but it requires Adobe Flash to be installed. Btw the situation is the same when it comes to the language used to style elements - there is only CSS.